# How to construct the hyperbolic embedding space for metric

Tags: physics

I'm having trouble going to different coordinates for the hyperbolic geometry metric:

$$dl^2=d\chi^2\, - \, \frac{1}{\kappa}\sinh^2(\sqrt{-\,\kappa}\,\,\chi)\,\big(\,d\theta^2 \, +\, \sin(\theta)^2 \,d\phi^2 \, \big), \,\,\,\,\,\, \kappa <0$$

How does one go to the hyperbolic embedding space with:

$$dL^2=(dX^1)^2+(dX^2)^2+(dX^3)^2-(dX^4)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&X_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\,\kappa}}\, \sinh(\sqrt{-\,\kappa}\,\,\chi) \sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\\
&X_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\,\kappa}}\, \sinh(\sqrt{-\,\kappa}\,\,\chi) \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
&X_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\,\kappa}}\, \sinh(\sqrt{-\,\kappa}\,\,\chi) \cos{\theta}\\
&X_4 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\,\kappa}}\, \cosh(\sqrt{-\,\kappa}\,\,\chi)
\end{align}